# try and catch PDO because he might escape with exception $e

Tags: pdo

Every tutorial online uses `try` and `catch` on any insert and update query by PDO. 
However, all the tutorial do not stop and explain why the value in `pdoexception` is `$e`?

```
try {
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM mypants ORDER by thebiggest'); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "too small"; //user friendly message
}
```

Why am I asking this stupid question? because I do not see a variable $e elsewhere!? why do we have to put `$e` beside the `PDOEXEPTION`? what does it do exactly? do I need to change the variable on every `try` and `catch` that I excute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
} catch(PDOException $e) {
```

... means catch an exception that is an instance of `PDOException`, and assign it to `$e`

To answer your question, `$e` doesn't already exist, it is assigned when the exception is caught.  Once the exception occurs `$e` will contain information about the exception which you can use for debugging, logging, or displaying to the screen.

`$e` is just a convention, you could call the variable whatever you like, and you don't need to worry about changing the variable on every `try` `catch`

Answer (score 0):

`$e` is the variable you want to put the exception in. It's not using an existing variable; it's similar to this:

```
$v = 6;
```

There, `$v` didn't exist before; the name only really matters to the code that uses it later.

Comment: in my case.. if I have one file with many "try and catch" statments.. do I need to use different values for PDOExeption?

Comment: @shnisaka: No. If you reuse a variable name, it will be overwritten, but in your code you're never using that variable, so it's not a problem.